# Clarification needed - the fundamental group of the circle

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I am reading the proof of $\mathbb{Z}\approx\pi_1(S^1)$ from Hatcher and didn't understand the **last paragraph** in the picture (the homomorphism part):

[image]

Isn't $\tau_m\tilde{\omega}_n:I\to \Bbb{R}$ and $\tau_m\tilde{\omega}_n(s)=ns+m$? So what is the image of $\tau_m\tilde{\omega}_n$ under $p$? It must be something like $\omega_?(s)=(\cos 2\pi (ns+m), \sin 2\pi (ns+m))$. But this loop doesn't look like $\omega_n$. Could you give me more detail? What part did I misunderstand?

Comment: Shifting by integer multiples of $2\pi$ doesn't change those two trig functions, so it is $\omega_n$. Explicitly, $\cos 2\pi(ns+m)=\cos(2\pi n s + 2\pi m)=\cos(2\pi n s)$ and similarly for sine.

Comment: Thank you Matt, it wasn't a great idea to learn algebraic topology without the basics...